# Display customer tax id in order notification mail - Opencart

Tags: email, notifications, opencart

I use Opencart 1.5.6 for the first time and I would like to display customer tax id (VAT number) in the order notification mail which is send to admin when customer confirm new order. Tax id should be displayed under customer payment address.

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: easiest solution: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=4137, i guess.

Comment: I have already used this extension but extension only mirror order notification email for customer to admin. I need tax id in order notification mail (in order.tpl) and this will be sent to customer and admin.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer on my question so I decided to create my own solution.

I have created an extension for Opencart and you can find it on the link.

Extension name: Display customer payment tax ID in order notification mail
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=16106